# SDL2 undefined reference sdl_Main in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, qt-creator, qmake

Im trying to use QtCreator to create a project including SDL2. But SDL is failing to compile correctly and I can't see the error.

My QtCreator .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Psiora
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        ui_mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += ui_mainwindow.h

FORMS    += ui_mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += "D:\devel\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2"

LIBS += -L"D:\devel\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" \
        -lmingw32 \
        -mwindows \
        -lSDL2main \
        -lSDL2
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED //Let QT Supply WinMain
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    UI_mainWindow win;
    win.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Compiler errors

> g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\Psiora.exe debug/main.o debug/ui_mainwindow.o debug/moc_ui_mainwindow.o  -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lqtmaind -LD:\devel\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -lmingw32 -mwindows -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -LD:\devel\Qt\5.2.1\mingw48_32\lib -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored
>
> D:\devel\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In function `console_main':
>
> /Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:140: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
>       collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't understand why SDL is giving an undefined reference to sdl_Main, when it has been linked in the correct order. I also don't get where this "/Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/" has come from when there is no such path on my computer, nor have I added the path myself.

My understanding is the SDL_Main provides WinMain however I wish to use the WinMain provided by Qt instead so I have defined the SDL_MAIN_HANDLED define to stop SDL using SDL_Main.

Addition Information:

- OS: Windows 8.1 Pro 32bit
- Compiler: MinGW 4.8 - The default one provided with the Qt Installer
- Qt: 5.2.1
- SDL 2.0.3 - Downloaded directly from libsdl.org, unmodified with no patches.

Comment: Can you tell us why you are trying to mix SDL and Qt?

Comment: I wrote an emulator in SDL which is complete and uses the 2D cross-platform rendering, timing and sound features of SDL. Now I am trying to add an interface and dialog windows, with the intention of redirecting SDL video output to a QWidget, allowing me to keep all my original code.

Comment: If I completely remove all traces of QT from the .pro and main.cpp file. It compiles and links fine.

Comment: the line "#include <QApplication>" makes the difference. uncommenting allows it to compile fine. Perhaps this is connected to both QT and SDL trying to provide WinMain?

Comment: Yes, Qt will expand it to qMain and WinMain will not find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your project file to solve this:

```
win32:QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENGTRY -= -lqtmain
win32-g++:DEFINES -= QT_NEEDS_QMAIN
```

or

```
CONFIG-= windows
QMAKE_LFLAGS += $$QMAKE_LFLAGS_WINDOWS
```

Comment: This has fixed my problem. Am i correct in thinking this removes the need for qtmain, allowing SDL to handle the WinMain conversion?

Comment: @Scott: yes, debao seems to have explained it [in here](http://blog.debao.me/2013/07/link-confilict-between-sdl-and-qt-under-windows/).

Comment: Thank you, that link is very informative and explains the issue very well.

Comment: How do I use these options without a Qt project (.pro) file? i.e. with CMakeLists.txt projects